# Convert WAV to AIFF with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I convert a wav file to an AIF file with ffmpeg?

I need to make various files one in 16 Bit, one in 24 bit and one in 32 Bit.

I also need to make different sample rates. E.g one in 176,400 kHz and one in 44,100 kHz.

I know `ffmpeg -i input-file.wav output-file.aif` will convert the file but I am not sure about the rest.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs says ffmpeg supports AIFF but there is no documentation on the AIFF encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format#AIFF-C_common_compression_types

Comment: According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FFmpeg it seems I can use `pcm_s8`, `pcm_s16be`, `pcm_s24be`, and `pcm_s32be` but I am not sure if this is the correct codec fot AIFF files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing `libavformat/aiff.h` shows:

```
static const AVCodecTag ff_codec_aiff_tags[] = {
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE,    MKTAG('N','O','N','E') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S8,       MKTAG('N','O','N','E') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_U8,       MKTAG('r','a','w',' ') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S24BE,    MKTAG('N','O','N','E') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S32BE,    MKTAG('N','O','N','E') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32BE,    MKTAG('f','l','3','2') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F64BE,    MKTAG('f','l','6','4') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW,     MKTAG('a','l','a','w') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW,    MKTAG('u','l','a','w') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S24BE,    MKTAG('i','n','2','4') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S32BE,    MKTAG('i','n','3','2') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_MACE3,        MKTAG('M','A','C','3') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_MACE6,        MKTAG('M','A','C','6') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_GSM,          MKTAG('G','S','M',' ') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G722,   MKTAG('G','7','2','2') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G726LE, MKTAG('G','7','2','6') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE,    MKTAG('t','w','o','s') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE,    MKTAG('s','o','w','t') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_QT, MKTAG('i','m','a','4') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_QDMC,         MKTAG('Q','D','M','C') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_QDM2,         MKTAG('Q','D','M','2') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_QCELP,        MKTAG('Q','c','l','p') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_SDX2_DPCM,    MKTAG('S','D','X','2') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_WS, MKTAG('A','D','P','4') },
    { AV_CODEC_ID_NONE,         0 },
};
```

Some of these only have decoding support in FFmpeg. See `ffmpeg -codecs` or `ffmpeg -encoders` or the first link you provided.

Comment: Your answer caused me to find a solution with Sox (that answer being 44100 24 bit signed Big Endian), so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-ar` option to set the sampling rate, and use `-sample_fmt` to "set the bit depth".

If you don't specify `-acodec` it will default to the muxer's default audio codec, which is `pcm_s16be` for `aiff` files, and that codec does not support all the bit depths you want.

```sh
# for each wav file in the directory, create an aiff file permutation across each bit depth and sample rate.
for FILE in *.wav; do
    # bit depths
    for BIT_DEPTH in 16 24 32; do
        # sampling rates
        for SAMPLING_RATE in 44100 176400; do

            # sample_fmt is determined by the codec, which is determined by the muxer.
            # So check the muxer used for the file you're trying to convert to:
            #
            # > ffmpeg -h muxer=aiff
            # Muxer aiff [Audio IFF]:
            #     Common extensions: aif,aiff,afc,aifc.
            #     Mime type: audio/aiff.
            #     Default video codec: png.
            #     Default audio codec: pcm_s16be.
            #
            # Now check for the specific encoder names for that codec:
            #
            # > ffmpeg -codecs | grep -P 'pcm_s\d\dbe'
            # DEAI.S pcm_s16be            PCM signed 16-bit big-endian
            # DEAI.S pcm_s16be_planar     PCM signed 16-bit big-endian planar
            # DEAI.S pcm_s24be            PCM signed 24-bit big-endian
            # DEAI.S pcm_s32be            PCM signed 32-bit big-endian
            # DEAI.S pcm_s64be            PCM signed 64-bit big-endian

            # and make sure you use only the appropriate arguments for each.
            SAMPLE_FMT="s${BIT_DEPTH}"
            if [[ "$BIT_DEPTH" -eq "24" ]]; then
                # pcm_s24be codec only supports s32 sample_fmt (check with `ffmpeg -h encoder=pcm_s24be`)
                SAMPLE_FMT="s32"
            fi

            ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -ar "$SAMPLING_RATE" -sample_fmt "$SAMPLE_FMT" -y -acodec "pcm_s${BIT_DEPTH}be" "${FILE%.wav}.$BIT_DEPTH.$SAMPLING_RATE.aiff"

        done
    done
done
```

Then you can get the details from the aiff files you created with `find *.aiff -exec ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream {} \;` to ensure they're of the correct sampling_rate and bit_depth.

#### Help output from ffmpeg:

```sh
└─[$] <> ffmpeg -h
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_9 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Getting help:
    -h      -- print basic options
    -h long -- print more options
    -h full -- print all options (including all format and codec specific options, very long)
    -h type=name -- print all options for the named decoder/encoder/demuxer/muxer/filter/bsf/protocol
    See man ffmpeg for detailed description of the options.

Print help / information / capabilities:
-L                  show license
-h topic            show help
-? topic            show help
-help topic         show help
--help topic        show help
-version            show version
-buildconf          show build configuration
-formats            show available formats
-muxers             show available muxers
-demuxers           show available demuxers
-devices            show available devices
-codecs             show available codecs
-decoders           show available decoders
-encoders           show available encoders
-bsfs               show available bit stream filters
-protocols          show available protocols
-filters            show available filters
-pix_fmts           show available pixel formats
-layouts            show standard channel layouts
-sample_fmts        show available audio sample formats
-colors             show available color names
-sources device     list sources of the input device
-sinks device       list sinks of the output device
-hwaccels           show available HW acceleration methods

Global options (affect whole program instead of just one file):
-loglevel loglevel  set logging level
-v loglevel         set logging level
-report             generate a report
-max_alloc bytes    set maximum size of a single allocated block
-y                  overwrite output files
-n                  never overwrite output files
-ignore_unknown     Ignore unknown stream types
-filter_threads     number of non-complex filter threads
-filter_complex_threads  number of threads for -filter_complex
-stats              print progress report during encoding
-max_error_rate maximum error rate  ratio of errors (0.0: no errors, 1.0: 100% errors) above which ffmpeg returns an error instead of success.
-bits_per_raw_sample number  set the number of bits per raw sample
-vol volume         change audio volume (256=normal)

Per-file main options:
-f fmt              force format
-c codec            codec name
-codec codec        codec name
-pre preset         preset name
-map_metadata outfile[,metadata]:infile[,metadata]  set metadata information of outfile from infile
-t duration         record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video
-to time_stop       record or transcode stop time
-fs limit_size      set the limit file size in bytes
-ss time_off        set the start time offset
-sseof time_off     set the start time offset relative to EOF
-seek_timestamp     enable/disable seeking by timestamp with -ss
-timestamp time     set the recording timestamp ('now' to set the current time)
-metadata string=string  add metadata
-program title=string:st=number...  add program with specified streams
-target type        specify target file type ("vcd", "svcd", "dvd", "dv" or "dv50" with optional prefixes "pal-", "ntsc-" or "film-")
-apad               audio pad
-frames number      set the number of frames to output
-filter filter_graph  set stream filtergraph
-filter_script filename  read stream filtergraph description from a file
-reinit_filter      reinit filtergraph on input parameter changes
-discard            discard
-disposition        disposition

Video options:
-vframes number     set the number of video frames to output
-r rate             set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)
-s size             set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)
-aspect aspect      set aspect ratio (4:3, 16:9 or 1.3333, 1.7777)
-bits_per_raw_sample number  set the number of bits per raw sample
-vn                 disable video
-vcodec codec       force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)
-timecode hh:mm:ss[:;.]ff  set initial TimeCode value.
-pass n             select the pass number (1 to 3)
-vf filter_graph    set video filters
-ab bitrate         audio bitrate (please use -b:a)
-b bitrate          video bitrate (please use -b:v)
-dn                 disable data

Audio options:
-aframes number     set the number of audio frames to output
-aq quality         set audio quality (codec-specific)
-ar rate            set audio sampling rate (in Hz)
-ac channels        set number of audio channels
-an                 disable audio
-acodec codec       force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)
-vol volume         change audio volume (256=normal)
-af filter_graph    set audio filters

Subtitle options:
-s size             set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)
-sn                 disable subtitle
-scodec codec       force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)
-stag fourcc/tag    force subtitle tag/fourcc
-fix_sub_duration   fix subtitles duration
-canvas_size size   set canvas size (WxH or abbreviation)
-spre preset        set the subtitle options to the indicated preset
```